# pst-solides3d: fill region under plot

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

How can I fill with [pst-solides3d](/questions/tagged/pst-solides3d) the region under the plot (x^2+y^2)/4 like in the following picture?

[image: fill region under (x^2+y^2)/4]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{139,000,000}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=20 40 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=25}
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,lightintensity=4}
\psset{unit=0.3}

\centering
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psSurface[ngrid=.25 .25,
  fillcolor=darkred,incolor=blue!40!white,
  axesboxed,
  Zmin=0,Zmax=8,
  action=draw**,
  linewidth=0.2pt](-4,-4)(4,4){x dup mul y dup mul add 4 div }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not really easy. You have to define new objects, the stripes (polygons) under the curve. The four edges and the face (plane):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{180,000,000}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psset{viewpoint=40 30 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=20,lightsrc=viewpoint}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(4,6)
  \psSurface[ngrid=16 16,hue=0 1,fillcolor=yellow!50,
     axesboxed,algebraic,Zmin=0,Zmax=8,
     action=draw**,linewidth=0.2pt](-4,-4)(4,4){ (x^2+y^2)/4 }
\pstVerb{
  /fct {dup mul 16 add 4 div} def
  /Sommets1 { %  y=4
    4 -0.5 -3.5 {/xi exch def
    xi 4 0 xi 0.5 sub 4 0 xi 0.5 sub dup 4 exch fct
    xi dup 4 exch fct } for } def
  /Faces1 {
    0 4 [Sommets2] length 3 idiv 4 sub { /iF exch def
    [ iF iF 1 add iF 2 add iF 3 add ] } for } def
  /Sommets2 { % x=4
    -4 0.5 3.5 {/yi exch def
       4 yi 0 4 yi 0.5 add 0 4 yi 0.5 add dup fct
       4 yi dup fct } for } def
  /Faces2 {
    0 4 [Sommets2] length 3 idiv 4 sub { /iF exch def
    [ iF iF 1 add iF 2 add iF 3 add ] } for } def
}%
\psSolid[object=new,sommets=Sommets1,faces={Faces1},
    fillcolor=darkred,linewidth=0.2pt]
\psSolid[object=new,sommets=Sommets2,faces={Faces2},
    fillcolor=darkred,linewidth=0.2pt]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Herbert. Thanks for your answer. I'll try to understand your object creation.

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to fill the visible space, i.e. the area below the border curves. On [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/) I recently showed how to do it answering: [Wie fülle ich das Volumen unterhalb eines Plots im Raum?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/8690/wie-fulle-ich-das-volumen-unterhalb-eines-plots-im-raum)

- Get the edge curves by fixing an x or y value
- Plot the edge curves and give the path a name
- Fill between named paths and the bottom line
- Optionally shade to improve the 3d impression
- Use layers if order of drawing would require it

[image]

Done with pfgplots, to show another approach:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
  \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
  \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      domain = -4:4,
      zmax   = 12,
      colormap/bone
    ]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
      \addplot3 [surf] {(x^2+y^2)/4};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none] (x,-4,0);
    \addplot3 [name path = yline, draw = none] (4,y,0);
    \addplot3 [name path = xcurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
      (x, -4, {(x^2+16)/4});
    \addplot3 [name path = ycurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
      (4, x, {(16+x^2)/4});
    \addplot [left color = black, right color = black!50, draw = none]
      fill between[of = xcurve and xline];
    \addplot [left color = black!50, right color = black, draw = none]
      fill between[of = yline and ycurve, reverse = true];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```